# move all to another table except id

Tags: php, mysql

move a record from `posts` to `archive`

```
$stmt = $db->prepare(
    "insert into archive (date, art, img, vid, title, subtitle, story, tags, status, user, pos, titlex, inde)
    select date, art, img, vid, title, subtitle, story, tags, status, user, pos, titlex, inde from posts
    where id = :aid"
);
```

don't tell me that there is no option like:
`move * except id...`

`id` is not movable due to a possible colision with archive's ids.

Comment: Just curious to know , why you want this. If you need you can use join to get data ?

Comment: @Shadow Unless I completely misread this question, it's nothing like the one you flagged it as a duplicate of.

Comment: @user2486, I don't want to `get` but `move` data.

Comment: @Shadows, pls read my post carefully enough.

Comment: Move is an `insert ... select ...` statement, therefore the duplicate applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option like `move`.. you'd need to insert it into one table and then delete it from the other.

However, you may want to reconsider your table design.  If you want to archive something, rather than having two separate tables that contain the same type of data, you should add a flag to your `posts` table to indicate whether or not an entry is archived or not.  Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD archived BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
```

When a post is normally added and it's not archived, the `archived` column is set to 0.  When you want to archive something, you just run an `UPDATE` statement setting it to 1 for that record.